# Chrome extension corrupted when open popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension crashes when try to open [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups). Error message appear in `chrome://extensions/`:

```
This extension may have been corrupted.
```

[image]

Other features, such as [context menu](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) and [options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) works fine.

Problem occurs only in version from Chrome Store. Debug version in developer mode works fine.

Basically problem occurred probably after some of chrome updates. Because extension had been working well for a long time and no changes to code was done.

The main problem that I have no info to identify the reason of the problem, because even [chrome logs](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) says nothing.

**Questions:**

Is there any way to identify reason of the issue? Maybe some special logs exists for this purpose?

Does anyone faced with such problem in chrome and was able to fix it?

Manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "ReportJ",
    "description": "The reporting helper for JIRA system.",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mishani0x0ef/reportj",
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["config.js", "js/urlService.js", "lib/jquery.min.js", "js/jira.js", "background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "ReportJ",
        "default_icon": "img/logo.png",
        "default_title": "ReportJ",
        "options_page": "options.html",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/logo.png",
        "48": "img/logo.png",
        "128": "img/logo128x128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["lib/jquery.min.js"],
        "matches": ["*://*.localhost/*"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Why are there `name` and `options_page` keys inside `browser_action`? They don't belong there...

Comment: @IvánNokonoko You are right. I have removed it. However it won't help me with the crash.

Comment: You might be using deprecated API. Also, I would recommend you to run your extensions in Chrome Canary. And if you have a Linux, you can try to run chromium via terminal, it has more verbose logs this way.

Comment: If some extension file size is a multiple of 4096 you probably hit https://crbug.com/720597 (fixed in Chrome 61).

Comment: Without, at an absolute bare minimum, a link to the affected extension, there is no way for us to know what the problem is. Even if someone has encountered a similar issue previously, there is no way to know that it is the *same* issue, because we have no way to duplicate your problem to determine the *exact* issue. Thus, we're reduced to **guessing**. While providing a link to the extension might enable us to take a look at the problem, it would still leave this question as off-topic, because all debugging questions require a [mcve] which duplicates the issue *in the question itself*.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required for debugging questions is that *we want to help*. If you want to [edit] the question to ask *only* if there are other, more complete/verbose logging options, then it won't be a debugging question (i.e. it won't be "why is my code not working") and might be on-topic.

Comment: @Makyen Here's the [link to the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reportj/hijbdbjoelgicnhnghhhlkpbhjdmchfg). I tried it in my computer (Chrome 60 on Linux) and I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Makyen Sorry for probable misunderstanding. Mine main question is "Where I can find at least some logs, stack trace, warning etc.?". Because currently I'm not able to get any info about reasons of crash and cannot provide you guys with them. I will try to paraphrase my question in other post.  P.S. Link to extension wasn't provided, because I was afraid that it could be treated as promotion or advertisement.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I have tried to run my extension on Chrome Canary 62.0.3184.0 and it works. Also I have find CSS file that multiply by 4096.)))) Please post it and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some file in the extension has size which is a multiple of 4096, you probably hit [bug#720597](https://crbug.com/720597), fixed in Chrome 61.

[kingychiu's .py script](https://gist.github.com/kingychiu/8faf23a3e42e864ae9ebd4c1b5939924) to test the sizes:

```python
import os
import glob
size_dir = {}
for filename in glob.iglob('./**/*.*', recursive=True):
  size =os.path.getsize(filename)
  if size % 4096 == 0 and size != 0:
    size_dir[filename] = os.path.getsize(filename)

for name, size in size_dir.items():
  print(name, size)
```

Windows .bat file:

```
@echo off
for /r %1 %%a in (*) do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set /a rem=%%~za %% 4096
  if !rem! == 0 echo %%a
  endlocal
)
pause
```

Windows .bat file that uses PowerShell:

```
@powershell -c ^
  "gci -r $(if('%1'){'%1'+'\*'}else{''}) | ?{ $_.Length%%4096 -eq 0 } | %%{ $_.FullName }"
@pause
```