# Chrome Extension doesn't work on Ubuntu despites it works on windows perfectly

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension

I'm working in a Chrome Extension, very simple, it just take a vector with dates to count the working days (no weekend or holiday). It works with bootstrap and soma JavaScript functions to count.

It works perfectly fine in windows, but I need them to work in Ubuntu too. After installation, when trying to open on Ubuntu, icon disappears from task bar. If I look at it on Extensions admin, it says the extension is damaged with a "Repair" button. Repairing it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know the cause? Any help will be appreciated.

Any documentation needed will be added on a edit.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: There was an [old bug in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668335/) so maybe you've hit a similar one.

Comment: Guess: may have to do with case-sensitivity of filenames?